# Rsync slows up SSH of every user connecting to the server

Tags: ssh, rsync

I manage a 36 core Ubuntu server at work, which is used only by a handful of people.

Every time when an user runs a rsync or scp job, all other users on the server experience a lot of typing lag with their SSH. I have tried limiting the amount of bandwidth the rsync job uses, moving the job to an idle CPU, lowering the priority of the job but none of them seemed to make the typing less laggy.

What would be the reason of the typing lag? What can I do to solve this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possibility: use your packet filter to prioritize TCP ACK, so that interactive, small packet exchanges do not get queued behind lots of rsync/scp data.  This has worked for me in situations which were not identical, but similar.  I last accomplished this using BSD pf, and don't have time to provide a proper answer doing the same with iptables or another ubuntu packet filter.

Comment: I just needed someone to point me to the right direction, so I can do some refined googling. Cheers.

Comment: Prioritising TCP ACK has kind of worked. It now lags around every 15 seconds than every few.

Comment: I set the length of the ack packets to <180. Would making this number smaller reduce the latency even further? Or is there something else I can do?

Comment: Another bit would be ensuring that ToS/DSCP values are respected (i.e., higher priority packets get to the front of the queue also).  The second octet of the IPv4 header (TOS/DSCP/ECN) is 0x10 for interactive ssh, 0x08 for scp/sftp/rsync.  Obviously, this is implementation dependent, but the standard linux versions (OpenSSH) do behave this way.